# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'XXX'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have created these types

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
hostels: Array<Maybe<Hostel>>;
hostel: Hostel;


if (hostels && hostels.length > 0) {
            hostel = hostels[0];
}
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Hostel'.
```

Comment: This `hostel: Hostel;` should be `hostel: Hostel| null;` Your list is `T|null` then first item should be of same type. Or you will have to typecast as `hostel = hostels[0] as Hostel;`

Comment: please check typescript assertions .<Hostel>hostels[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast answer is to disable `strictNullChecks` in your tsconfig.json (or command line, or whatever you are using to configure typescript) so you can assign `null` to almost everything, even without needing to set the typings to `null`. Is like having all definitions include `| null` implicitly.

If you still require `strictNullChecks` enabled, then the types must match. The same way a `string` variable can only receive `string` types, `hostel` must be the same type as `Maybe<Hostel>`, which is `Hostel | null`, so:

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
hostels: Array<Maybe<Hostel>>;
hostel: Hostel | null;

if (hostels && hostels.length > 0) {
    hostel = hostels[0];
}
```